# speedup autocomplete : what data structure to use to store data in the cache

Tags: caching, data-structures, memcached

I want to design a autocomplete, where instead of searching on database, I want to precook in to the cache and search on that. What could be the best Datastructure to do that on Java.util package? Looks like LinkedList is fitting in to it. Anybody designed such a system?

Answer (score 0):

The Java `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` types are extremely useful for building caches.  They behave just like regular hash containers, but have support for LRU cache eviction if you so choose.  The "linked" part of these containers refers to the fact that there's a linked list threaded through them, so hopefully they're what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!